# htaccess errordocument not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

My understanding is that to show a custom error page, one must put

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

in .htaccess

Also,

```
AllowOverride All
```

must be set in httpd.conf file. However, right now it's set to

```
AllowOverride None
```

If I change None to All, then restart the server, I get a Internal Server Error 500 when I deliberately enter gibberish in the address bar. What am I doing wrong?

Other things in the file

```
IndexIgnore *
```

followed by

```
RewriteEngine on
```

followed by rewrite rules.

RewriteEngine on is the cause of the problem--see below.

Comment: is there anything else in your htaccess file?

Comment: Look in the server's error logs what the exact error message is about.

Comment: So I found the error log:

`[Sat Aug 17 17:33:46 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Data/MyWeb/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

I'm guessing this started when I set up Apache on my new PC and haven't noticed the problem until now.  The script worked previously.

Comment: @Gary Please delete your question or send the answer and mark it!

Comment: The answer is to ensure that `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented in httpd.conf

Comment: @Gary This is Q&A site: you asked question, then must be an answer! it will help others to solve their problem easier if you send it as separated answer not a comment!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** This error means you forgot to enable the `rewrite` module and is not related to `ErrorDocument`.

**How to fix it?**

Make sure you have enabled the `rewrite` module. This can be done by doing one of the following:

1. Uncommenting `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in your Apache configuration file.
2. Run `a2enmod rewrite` as root (*only available on Debian-based systems*).

**Why are you only getting this error after you added ErrorDocument?**

`AllowOverride` was set to `None`, which means your .htaccess will be completely ignored. Later, you set it to `All` to enable .htaccess files.

However, you forgot to enable the `rewrite` module but you tried to use it in your .htaccess. This is not related to `ErrorDocument` and is simply a coincidence. The following error you posted is clearly showing it:

> `[Sat Aug 17 17:33:46 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Data/MyWeb/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`